# Mac - Back up only a particular folder using time machine

Tags: mac, time-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I tell Apple's Time Machine to backup a single folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/143983/can-i-tell-apples-time-machine-to-backup-a-single-folder)

I am a developer on Mac. But I never used Time Machine feature.
How can I back up only one folder using time machine.

Comment: Just to be sure: Time Machine is not a revision control system.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Time Machine preferences only allow you to set which drives/folders you want to ignore, not which ones you want to back up. You can get the behavior you want by excluding all the folders you don't want backed up, but it's kind of cumbersome. I suggest using [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or some kind of [VCS](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRevision_control&ei=uj33TMvEPMK88gaO3ZizCQ&usg=AFQjCNEwAPKvqdiGWxq-vtrixeewoIU78g&sig2=8DXpYBG7V9EZYZ1cSF8a4A) if you only want to incrementally back up one folder.